# Dictionary without generics

Tags: c#, base-class

I'm learning C# and I have an exercise with these three classes:

```
public abstract BaseClass<T> Where T : BaseClass<T>

public class Class1

public class Class2 : BaseClass<Class2>
```

On the exercise there is this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary { [class1] = class1, [class2] = class2 };
```

I think that here, `Dictionary` is a shortcut for `Dictionary<object, object>`
; so I have added this class to the project:

```
public class Dictionary : Dictionary<object, object>
```

My problem here is that I'm not sure if I have declared correctly `Dictionary`. Now the exercise works perfectly but maybe there is another option to declare `Dictionary`. By the way, I have used `dynamic` instead of `object` and it also works.

My question is:

In the exercise, is `Dictionary` a custom class or is another class from .NET Framework or whatever that I don't know?

Comment: There is no non-generic `Dictionary` class.  You should not do that.

Comment: @SLaks If I should not do that; what do I have to do to make `var dictionary = new Dictionary { [class1] = class1, [class2] = class2 };` compiles?

Comment: @SLaks That is a pretty bad exercise.

Comment: Not directing this at the OP, but rather at the exercise - this reminds me of questions that involve `ArrayList` where you can tell the material predates .NET 2.0. (Except in this case no one knows where this came from.) I've had experience with college instructors who taught .NET but clearly weren't familiar with it, and spent 30 minutes trying to figure out why something simple wouldn't compile. I don't have all the facts, but this is as bad as it appears at face value I would dump this class. If you paid for it you should get your money back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax from the exercise is invalid:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary {
    [class1] = class1
,   [class2] = class2
};
```

This looks like a C# 6 dictionary initializer, which expects type parameters of the dictionary to be specified explicitly:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<object,object> {
    [class1] = class1
,   [class2] = class2
};
```

You do not need to create your own class derived from `Dictionary<TKey,TVal>`, or use `dynamic`.

**Note:** Using `object` for both key and value type is required because your dictionary example uses classes `Class1` and `Class2` as both keys and values, while the classes have no common ancestor other than `object`.

**Edit:**

> I can't modify the exercise. So, I need to do something to make it compile

Your solution that derives `Dictionary` from `Dictionary<object,object>` is fine then. You can also write your own `Dictionary` class that takes a dictionary-like initializer, but that would be a much harder exercise.

Comment: I can't modify the exercise. So, I need to do something to make it compiles. And I don't know if the solution I use, it is good or not. Maybe I can use an alias also. Yes, I know, it is a very bad exercise.

Comment: @VansFannel, I've provided a code snippet on how to do that in my answer, please check below.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, it looks like collection initializer will work out of the box if you inherit from Dictionary, although I agree that in real life, you would very rarely need to actually inherit from a dictionary.

Comment: "The syntax from the exercise is invalid". It is not invalid, nor is it a "dictionary initializer". There is no such thing as a "dictionary initializer". It's an object initlializer applied to an indexer.

Comment: @Adrian you're wrong.The syntax is invalid and this is collection initializer more specifically a dictionary initializer as this was introduced in C#6 as a special feature for the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`  type. It does uses the indexer rather than the `Add` method tho, you're right on this one.

Comment: @Deadzone No you are wrong, and look into the C# 6.0 spec. There is no "dictionary initializer". It is not a special feature for dictionaries, it can be used with *any* class that has an indexer. see my own answer below!

Answer (score 1):

In .NET [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) class is generic, and there is no other class named `Dictionary` in BCL.
You can get a similar functionality form the predescessor - [HashTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx) that also implements [IDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) interface

Note, that there is **no need to inherit** from Dictionary - just use the instance of generic class with the types you need, or use a Hashtable.

If you are in doubt if a specific class is in the BCL or not - check it's namespace.

If you are curious about it's implementation check [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Specifically for your exersise, it looks like you have to inherit from Dictionary and use a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer):

**Note: Don't inherit from Dictionary in production code, most of the times it is unnecessary.**

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T> {}

        public class Class1 { }

        public class Class2 : BaseClass<Class2> { }

        private class Dictionary : Dictionary<Class1, Class2> { }

        public void Test()
        { 
            var dictionary = new Dictionary { { new Class1(), new Class2() } };
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, having this `public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T> {}` is an example of [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), @Eric Lippert wrote a nice article on that - see [Curiouser and curiouser](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/)

Comment: I don't have any namespace to check. Make the line `var dictionary = new Dictionary { [class1] = class1, [class2] = class2 };` compiles is part of the exercise.

Comment: @VansFannel, how about `var dictionary = new Dictionary<Class1,Class2>();`

Comment: No, I can't change the content of the exercise.

Comment: @VansFannel, you can't use the generic Dictionary class without specifying the type arguments. If you can't specify them, looks like you need to create your own class, although it seems strange.

Comment: Yes, it is very strange. This is why I'm asking it. It looks like a trap.

Comment: @VansFannel, yes it does - I will post a code snippet shortly on how to do that

Comment: If "make the line compile" is the exercise, wouldn't adding the appropriate generic arguments be the solution? Perhaps you've misunderstood the exercise because otherwise it seems strange to me.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, I thought so as well, and suggested the same, but the author of the question said that he cannot add generic arguments, see comments above.

Comment: I was responding to him, not to you

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary { [class1] = class1, [class2] = class2 };
```

uses an *object initializer* to initialize the indexer of the `Dictionary` class. This syntax is supported from C# Version 6 (see C# 6.0 Language Specification under section *§7.6.11.2 Object initializers*).

As you correctly found out, one way to get a class that allows such an behavoir is to derive a class from `Dictionary<T,K>`. Another way is to write a `Dictionary` class that uses an indexer. The simplest class that exhibits such a behavior is:

```
public class Dictionary
{
    public object this[object index] {
        get {return null;}
        set {}
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();
    var dictionary = new Dictionary 
    {
        [class1] = class1, 
        [class2] = class2
    };
}
```

Which does not do anything, obviously, but it shows where the initialization syntax comes from.

Comment: Thanks. Is this better than inherit from Dictionary?

Comment: For the purpose of having a working implementation, no. But it is the most simple solution to the given problem.